# How to resize folders on desktop

Tags: desktop

At some point I changed some setting - I am not quite sure how, maybe via some sequence of keystrokes, and my folders all got bigger on my desktop.

I don't think this looks very aesthetic, how do I change the size?

This is what they look like:

[image: Big folders]

Answer (score 1):

With the Desktop in focus, press cmd-J to open view options and adjust the Icon size slider.

> [image]

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchldaafb302/mac

Answer (score 1):

To resize desktop icons :

- Control-click on the desktop.
- Choose **Show View Options**, then use the **Icon size** slider to make changes.